# Use Ajax request using X-Auth-Token in angularjs controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, controller, get

I've a little problem with my request to an external API which use X-Auth-Token :

```js
'user strict';
app.controller("controller" ,function($scope,$http) {
    
    $scope.result = $.ajax({
      headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': '*****' },
      url: 'http://api.************',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
       return data;
       
      }
    }); 
    console.log($scope.result);
});
```

the result of the code is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BjL0.png)

When i try to do this :

```js
console.log($scope.result.responseJSON);
```

The result is this one an undefined object.
Any ideas about this problem ?

Comment: why are you using `$.ajax` and not `$http` in an angular app?

Comment: I don't know how to use the X-Auth-Token with the $http !

Comment: headers are explained in the docs

Comment: angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute' ])
...
.controller('home', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('token').success(function(token) {
    $http({
      url : 'http://localhost:9000',
      method : 'GET',
      headers : {
        'X-Auth-Token' : token.token
      }
    }).success(function(data) {
      $scope.greeting = data;
    });
  })
});

Comment: I found a solution here : https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/the-resource-server-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iii

Answer (score 1):

The function `$.ajax()` doesn't return the result, since it's asynchronous. Instead your result is given to you through the `success` callback. So your code should look like this:

```
'user strict';
app.controller("controller" ,function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.init = function(){
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': '*****' },
            url: 'http://api.************',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
                $scope.result = data;
            }
        }); 
    };

    $scope.init();
});
```

Note: you could use `$http.get(..)` instead of `$.ajax(..)`. It returns something called a Promise and is more common in angular applications. The usage is quite similar to the above. It's something like this:

```
$http.get('http://api.************', {
    headers: {
       'X-Auth-Token': '*****'
    },
    responseType: 'json'
}).then(function(result){
    $scope.result = result;
});
```

You probably ought to separate the api requests into a service. If you find a good angular styleguide/best practices tutorial, you should get some valuable pointers.